# Alpine 3.18 Docker image not respecting `sleep` shell command after a background command run with &

Tags: docker, shell, sh, alpine-linux

I've been using a simple script with a while loop inside it as the entry point to a Docker container to run a command every minute. A sort of simple cronjob so to speak. The while loop looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

while [ true ]
do
  php script.php &
  sleep 60
done
```

This has been working fine until I updated the base image to be built off of Alpine 3.18, and it now no longer respects the `sleep 60` command and just reruns the php script immediately.

You can test this by running the following simple docker locally with versions 3.17 and 3.18 of Alpine respectively:

```bash
docker run --rm -it alpine:3.17 sh -c "while [ true ]; do echo 1 & sleep 3; done;"
```

Correctly runs and waits 3 seconds in between echoing `1`.

```bash
docker run --rm -it alpine:3.18 sh -c "while [ true ]; do echo 1 & sleep 3; done;"
```

Just starts streaming `1`'s to the screen without sleeping for 3 seconds.

Has something changed in the syntax for a shell script in 3.18 and/or BusyBox? Just as a note, the script has the same issue be it a one liner like the `docker run` example, or in it's own `.sh` file formatted like the top example.

Comment: Could you extract the busybox versions for these images so folks can test for a regression/bug between them without using Docker? (I'm assuming that `/bin/sh` in those images is busybox ash, but that might be worth confirming too).

Comment: Looks like the 3.17 alpine image is using `BusyBox v1.35.0 (2022-11-19 10:13:10 UTC) multi-call binary.` and the 3.18 alpine image is using `BusyBox v1.36.1 (2023-06-02 00:42:02 UTC) multi-call binary.`

Comment: Hmm. 1.36.1 has several changes specific to sleep, 1.36.0 has several general ash signal-handling changes; nothing is an outright smoking gun from the changelog, but I'd certainly believe unintended side effects; lessee if a `git bisect` can run it down to an individual committish...

Comment: (expanding on Mark Cameron's comment) indeed this seems to be a busybox related issue.  As a workaround you could `apk add dash-binsh` so `/bin/sh` is provided by a less unpredictable executable?

Comment: @MarkCameron, ...okay, good news: this is reproducible without musl libc or alpine; happens with a stock glibc build of busybox ash, which is going to make running down the regression _very_ easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in busybox ash that has already been fixed upstream but not included in a release (as of this writing, at which point v1.36.1 is the latest available).

The fix is included in commit [7362d2979434c565ae70b0ccf9d4b09d7597fb48](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=7362d2979434c565ae70b0ccf9d4b09d7597fb48); you can thus expect this behavior to no longer take place when a new busybox release is next available.

As [suggested by Grobu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76687757/alpine-3-18-docker-image-not-respecting-sleep-shell-command-after-a-background/76688297#comment135203632_76687757), you might switch to dash in the interim: this bug is related to busybox trying to call its own `sleep`.

Comment: Ok great thanks, will keep an eye out for an updated BusyBox release before retrying with 3.18